# Apache Storm Problem: "Unable to canonicalize address localhost/<unresolved>:2000 because it's not resolvable"

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, localhost, apache-storm

When I launch a simple Strorm script on IntellijIdea or Eclipse i encounter this problem: "Unable to canonicalize address localhost/:2000 because it's not resolvable".

```java
import org.apache.storm.*;
import org.apache.storm.generated.*;
import org.apache.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.*;
import org.apache.storm.utils.Utils;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class ExclamationExample {
    public static class TestWordSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
        private SpoutOutputCollector _collector;

        @Override
        public void open(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, SpoutOutputCollector spoutOutputCollector) {
            _collector = spoutOutputCollector;
        }

        @Override
        public void nextTuple() {
            Utils.sleep(100);
            final String[] words = new String[]{"nathan", "mike", "jackson", "golda", "bertels"};
            final Random rand = new Random();
            final String word = words[rand.nextInt(words.length)];
            _collector.emit(new Values(word));
            System.out.printf("Word spout: %s\n", word);
        }

        @Override
        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
            outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
        }
    }

    public static class ExclamationBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
        private OutputCollector collector;

        @Override
        public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
            this.collector = collector;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
            String val = tuple.getString(0) + "!!!";
            collector.emit(tuple, new Values(val));
            System.out.printf("Exclamation bolt: %s\n", val);
            collector.ack(tuple);
        }

        @Override
        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
            declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
        }
    }

    //TOPOLOGY
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Config conf = new Config();
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        builder.setSpout("word", new TestWordSpout(), 2);
        builder.setBolt("exclaim1", new ExclamationBolt(), 2).shuffleGrouping("word");
        builder.setBolt("exclaim2", new ExclamationBolt(), 2).shuffleGrouping("exclaim1");

        conf.setDebug(false);

        String topologyName = "test";

        conf.setNumWorkers(2);

        //If there are arguments, we are running on a cluster
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            conf.setNumWorkers(3);
            topologyName = args[0];
            StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, conf, builder.createTopology());
        }

        try (LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster()) {
            cluster.submitTopology(topologyName, conf, builder.createTopology());
            Utils.sleep(600000); // wait [param] ms
            cluster.killTopology(topologyName);
            cluster.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What is a possible solution?

Comment: Show us the script.

Comment: The script is this: https://github.com/domenico138/storm/blob/master/Storm/src/ExclamationExample.java

Comment: I execute the script in Local Mode, as LocalCluster, using Maven. With another computer everything works, but with my computer I received this error!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. If can help someone i tell the solution. I ran the Java Application using Java SDK 17, this give me problem, then I created new project with JDK 1.8 and everything works!